# Directory JTree Performance

Tags: java, performance, object-oriented, swing

The purpose of this short program is to:

- Detect all accessible local drives and USB drives
- List all the accessible directories for each drive which do not require administrator privileges or are hidden by the system
- Display all the data in a friendly UI that is simple to use and nice to look at

I have noticed once the list starts to become longer the performance of the list scrolling and animations decreases. Therefore I would particularly be interested in your thoughts on the efficiency of the program and if any improvements can be made to it. I would also like to know if you think the program does what it is meant to do properly.

[Dropbox Folder with source code and icons](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8eccatpvlpo1lvs/AACbjoBw-7vaZTFQpHXaaF_0a?dl=0)

[image: Example of the program]

<sup>*Example of the program*</sup>

**Edit**

I know there is a lot of code for what seems like a simple component so I will add the performance issues that I hinted at earlier on in my question and what I think might be causing them.

As the list grows:

- The scrolling becomes jumpy and sometimes lags. This is while there are only a few rows on the screen is ~250 on my system.
- The expand control fade animation becomes slow with ~30 rows on my system. I believe this is being caused by the way the timers work in `TreeHandleUI.fadeHandles(boolean show, int msDur)`
- The "rollover" tracking when the mouse one of the rows or expand controls for a row can have a significant delay of almost half a second if the number of rows is ~200 on my system.

Another performance issue that I noted is when a directory has a large amount of subdirectories in it and files it can take a while to open. An example in Windows would be `C:\Program Files`. This is because the method `ComputerDirectoryTreeModel.listDirectories(File path)` has to check every file to see if it is a directory. Then for paint controls and to determine what icons should be used there is also `ComputerDirectoryTreeModel.hasDirectory(File path)` and `FileNameRenderer.hasDirectory(File path)`. This is a method with improved efficiency over `listDirectories` as it stops as soon as it finds one directory in the directory it is searching. The problem is if the directory is large and does not actually contain a directory or the directory is a far way down the list then this can still take a while to run.

---

**JFileTreeIE.java** - Implementation of program

```
package tree;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import tree.design.DesignTree;
import tree.model.ComputerDirectoryTreeModel;

/*
 * Short implementation class to show the program
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JFileTreeIE extends JFrame {
    private JFileTreeIE() {
        super("Directory Explorer");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        createPanel();
        setSize(500, 800);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createPanel() {
        DesignTree tree = new DesignTree(new ComputerDirectoryTreeModel());
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tree);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(scroll);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new JFileTreeIE());
    }
}
```

**DesignTree.java** - The component class

```
package tree.design;

import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

import tree.listeners.MouseHandler;
import tree.render.FileNameRenderer;
import tree.ui.TreeHandleUI;

/*
 * Class to set a range of custom UIs, renderers, and handlers
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DesignTree extends JTree {
    public DesignTree(TreeModel model) {
        super(model);

        setUI(new TreeHandleUI(this));
        setCellRenderer(new FileNameRenderer());

        setRootVisible(false); //Allows for each drive to act as a root
        setShowsRootHandles(true); //Shows handles for each individual drive

        getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        addMouseListener(new MouseHandler(this));
    }
}
```

**AlphaImageIcon.java** - Slightly edited version of code from [this post](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/alpha-icons/) - Used for icon animations

```
package tree.icon;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 * An Icon  wrapper that paints the contained icon with a specified transparency.
 * <P>
 * This class is suitable for wrapping an <CODE>ImageIcon</CODE>
 * that holds an animated image.  To show a non-animated Icon with transparency,
 * the companion class {@link AlphaIcon} is a lighter alternative.
 *
 * @version 1.0 08/16/10
 * @author Darryl
 * 
 * https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/alpha-icons/
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AlphaImageIcon extends ImageIcon {
    private Icon icon;
    private Image image;
    private float alpha;

    public AlphaImageIcon(Icon icon, float alpha) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    @Override
    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void setImage(Image image) {
        if (icon instanceof ImageIcon)
            ((ImageIcon) icon).setImage(image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getImageLoadStatus() {
        if (icon instanceof ImageIcon)
            return ((ImageIcon) icon).getImageLoadStatus();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageObserver getImageObserver() {
        if (icon instanceof ImageIcon)
            return ((ImageIcon) icon).getImageObserver();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageObserver(ImageObserver observer) {
        if (icon instanceof ImageIcon)
            ((ImageIcon) icon).setImageObserver(observer);
    }

    public float getAlpha() {
        return alpha;
    }

    public Icon getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        if (icon instanceof ImageIcon)
            image = ((ImageIcon) icon).getImage();
        else
            image = null;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcAtop.derive(alpha));
        icon.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return icon.getIconWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return icon.getIconHeight();
    }
}
```

**MouseHandler.java** - Main `MouseListener` for the tree

```
package tree.listeners;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import tree.ui.TreeHandleUI;

/*
 * Class which controls expand / collapse handle animations
 * and other mouse related functions
 */

public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
    JTree t = null;
    TreeHandleUI tUI = null;

    public MouseHandler(JTree tree) {
        t = tree;
        tUI = (TreeHandleUI) tree.getUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        tUI.fadeHandles(true, 300); //Fades handles in
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        tUI.fadeHandles(false, 300); //Fades handles out
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //Clears selection when mouse is pressed outside of on of the nodes
        if((SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) || SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
                && t.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY()) == -1)
            t.clearSelection();
    }
}
```

**ComputerDirectoryTreeModel.java** - The `TreeModel` that detects the drives and automatically generates the list of directories for each drive

```
package tree.model;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;

/*
 * Class that automatically generates the tree
 * so that it contains all directories accessible drives.
 * 
 * Does not access hidden directories or directories
 * that require administrator privileges.
 */

public class ComputerDirectoryTreeModel implements TreeModel {
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();

    public ComputerDirectoryTreeModel() {
        createRootLayout();
    }

    private void createRootLayout() {
        for(File path : File.listRoots()) { //Loops through the "root" directories on a computer - Determined by system
            if(path.exists())
                if(addable(path))
                    if(listDirectories(path).length != 0)
                        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(path));
        }
    }

    //Checks whether the drive can be added
    //Only adds local drives or USBs
    private boolean addable(File path) {
        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
        String type = fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(path);
        //System.out.println(type); //For Debugging Purposes
        if(type != null) {
            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Local Disk"))
                return true;
            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("USB Drive"))
                return true;
            return true; //Temporary fix for users who don't use windows
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Not used
    @Override
    public void addTreeModelListener(javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener l) {}

    //Overrides the original getChild so that the method returns the correct directory
    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        if(parent != root && parent instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            File f = (File) (((DefaultMutableTreeNode) parent).getUserObject());
            return listDirectories(f)[index];
        } else if(parent != root) {
            File f = (File) parent;
            return listDirectories(f)[index];
        }
        return root.getChildAt(index);
    }

    //Overrides the original getChildCount so that
    //the method returns the correct value
    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        if(parent != root && parent instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            File f = (File) (((DefaultMutableTreeNode) parent).getUserObject());
            if (!f.isDirectory())
                return 0;
            else
                return listDirectories(f).length;
        } else if(parent != root) {
            File f = (File) parent;
            if (!f.isDirectory())
                return 0;
            else
                return listDirectories(f).length;
        }
        return root.getChildCount();
    }

    //Overrides the original hasChildren so that
    //the method returns the correct value
    public boolean hasChildren(Object parent) {
        if(parent != root && parent instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            File f = (File) (((DefaultMutableTreeNode) parent).getUserObject());
            if (!f.isDirectory())
                return false;
            else
                return hasDirectory(f);
        } else if(parent != root) {
            File f = (File) parent;
            if (!f.isDirectory())
                return false;
            else
                return hasDirectory(f);
        }
        return root.getChildCount() != 0 ? true : false;
    }

    //Overrides the original getIndexOfChild so that
    //the method returns the correct value
    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        if(parent != root && parent instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            File par = (File) (((DefaultMutableTreeNode) parent).getUserObject());
            File ch = (File) child;
            return Arrays.asList(listDirectories(par)).indexOf(ch);
        } else if(parent != root) {
            File par = (File) parent;
            File ch = (File) child;
            return Arrays.asList(listDirectories(par)).indexOf(ch);
        }

        return root.getIndex((TreeNode) child);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    //There should technically be no leaves as every directory
    //could potentially have a sub directory in it.
    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        return false;
    }

    //Not used
    @Override
    public void removeTreeModelListener(javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener l) {}

    //Not used
    @Override
    public void valueForPathChanged(javax.swing.tree.TreePath path, Object newValue) {}

    //Lists all the sub directories of the given directory
    //if it is accessible. This will not work for folders
    //that require administrator privilages to view.
    private File[] listDirectories(File path) {
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<File>();
        for(File temp : path.listFiles()) {
            if(temp.isDirectory() && !temp.isHidden())
                if(temp.listFiles() != null)
                    arrayList.add(temp);
        }

        return arrayList.toArray(new File[0]);
    }

    //Written to improve performance of listDirectories(path) != 0
    private boolean hasDirectory(File path) {
        for(File temp : path.listFiles()) {
            if(temp.isDirectory() && !temp.isHidden())
                if(temp.listFiles() != null)
                    return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**FileNameRenderer.java** - Makes sure that the rows are rendered correctly

```
package tree.render;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;

/*
 * This class handles the rendering of the tree nodes.
 * This includes handling rollover functions, and naming conventions.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FileNameRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    public FileNameRenderer() {
        setBackgroundSelectionColor(new Color(205, 232, 255));
        setHoverSelectionColor(new Color(229, 243, 255));
    }

    private boolean mOver = false;
    private boolean selected = false;
    private Color rolloverColor = null;

    public void setHoverSelectionColor(Color rollover) {
        rolloverColor = rollover;
    }

    public Color getHoverSelectionColor() {
        return rolloverColor;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        return getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus, false);
    }

    //Replaces the node text from the path of the directory to just the directory name
    //Also update the what node is selected and whether the mouse is over it for other
    //functions in this class
    //Sets some of the icons of the nodes on the tree. Ie if the directory is expanded
    //the icon will change
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus, boolean mouseOver) {
        File holder = null;
        if(value instanceof File) {
            holder = (File) value;
            if(!Arrays.asList(File.listRoots()).contains((File) value)) {
                value = ((File) value).getName();
            }
        }

        JComponent c = (JComponent) super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

        selected = sel;
        mOver = mouseOver;

        if(c instanceof JLabel)
            ((JLabel) c).setText("<html><p style=\"padding: 3px 0;\">" + value + "<p/>");

        if(value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)
            setIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/root.png"));
        else if(expanded && holder != null && hasDirectory(holder))
            setIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/open-folder.png"));
        else
            setIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/folder.png"));

        return c;
    }

    //Checks whether the directory has any sub directories.
    //This determines if a handle will be painted next to
    //the node
    private boolean hasDirectory(File path) {
        for(File temp : path.listFiles()) {
            if(temp.isDirectory() && !temp.isHidden())
                if(temp.listFiles() != null)
                    return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    //Paints the node
    //Changes background colour of the node if the mouse is over it
    //or if it is selected
    //Offsets paint by so much so that the node works with the icons
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Color bColor;

        if (selected)
            bColor = getBackgroundSelectionColor();
        else if(mOver)
            bColor = getHoverSelectionColor();
        else {
            bColor = getBackgroundNonSelectionColor();
            if (bColor == null)
                bColor = getBackground();
        }

        int imageOffset = -1;
        if (bColor != null) {
            imageOffset = getLabelStart();
            g.setColor(bColor);
            if(getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight())
                g.fillRect(imageOffset, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight());
            else
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight());
        }

        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    //Used for getting the image offset for the paintComponent function
    private int getLabelStart() {
        Icon currentI = getIcon();
        if(currentI != null && getText() != null)
            return currentI.getIconWidth() + Math.max(0, getIconTextGap() - 1);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**TreeHandleUI.java** - Look and feel of the tree

```
package tree.ui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

import tree.icon.AlphaImageIcon;
import tree.model.ComputerDirectoryTreeModel;
import tree.render.FileNameRenderer;

/*
 * This mainly handles the look and feel of the JTree
 * It effects areas such as the expand controls of nodes,
 * the way the nodes look, and how lines are drawn on the
 * tree if they are drawn at all
 */

public class TreeHandleUI extends BasicTreeUI {
    ///Variables
    private JTree t = null;
    private boolean lines = false;
    private boolean lineTypeDashed = true;
    private Icon rolloverIcon = null;
    private boolean iconRolloverEnabled = false;
    private ArrayList<Timer> timers = new ArrayList<Timer>(); //For preventing any nasty glitching if fade method is still running
    private UpdateHandler uH = null;
    private ComputerDirectoryTreeModel tM; //Used so that we can quickly check if the file contains any children
    private boolean isLeftToRight(Component c) {
        return c.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight();
    }

    private int count = 0;
    private float val = 0F;

    ///Constructors
    //Sets most of the icons for the JTree and changes the default mouse handler
    public TreeHandleUI(JTree tree) {
        t = tree;
        uH = new UpdateHandler(t);
        t.addMouseMotionListener(uH);

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> tM = (ComputerDirectoryTreeModel) treeModel); //Is like this so that tM does not return an NPE
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> setCollapsedIcon(new AlphaImageIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/closed.png"), 0F)));
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> setExpandedIcon(new AlphaImageIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/open.png"), 0F)));
        setRolloverIcon(new AlphaImageIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/rollover.png") , 1F));
        removeLines(true); //Removes all the visible lines on the JTree
    }

    ///Methods
    //Methods used for rollover icon
    public void setRolloverIcon(Icon rolloverG) {
        Icon oldValue = rolloverIcon;
        rolloverIcon = rolloverG;
        setIconRolloverEnabled(true);
        if (rolloverG != oldValue) {
            t.repaint();
        }
    }

    private void setIconRolloverEnabled(boolean handleRolloverEnabled) {
        boolean oldValue = iconRolloverEnabled;
        iconRolloverEnabled = handleRolloverEnabled;
        if (handleRolloverEnabled != oldValue) {
            t.repaint();
        }
    }

    //Paints the correct icon for the expand control
    //Ie when the mouse is over the collapsed icon it
    //changes to the rollover icon
    @Override
    protected void paintExpandControl(Graphics g,
                                      Rectangle clipBounds, Insets insets,
                                      Rectangle bounds, TreePath path,
                                      int row, boolean isExpanded,
                                      boolean hasBeenExpanded,
                                      boolean isLeaf) {
        Object value = path.getLastPathComponent();

        if(tM.hasChildren(value)) {
            int middleXOfKnob;
            if(isLeftToRight(t))
                middleXOfKnob = bounds.x - getRightChildIndent() + 1;
            else
                middleXOfKnob = bounds.x + bounds.width + getRightChildIndent() - 1;
            int middleYOfKnob = bounds.y + (bounds.height / 2);

            if(isExpanded) {
                Icon expandedIcon = getExpandedIcon();
                if(expandedIcon != null)
                  drawCentered(tree, g, expandedIcon, middleXOfKnob, middleYOfKnob );
            } else if(isLocationInExpandControl(path, uH.getXPos(), uH.getYPos())
                    & !isExpanded && iconRolloverEnabled) {
                if(row == uH.getRowHandle()) {
                    if(rolloverIcon != null)
                        drawCentered(tree, g, rolloverIcon, middleXOfKnob, middleYOfKnob);
                } else {
                    Icon collapsedIcon = getCollapsedIcon();
                    if(collapsedIcon != null)
                      drawCentered(tree, g, collapsedIcon, middleXOfKnob, middleYOfKnob);
                }
            } else {
                Icon collapsedIcon = getCollapsedIcon();
                if(collapsedIcon != null)
                  drawCentered(tree, g, collapsedIcon, middleXOfKnob, middleYOfKnob);
            }
        }
    }

    //Paints the row, updates background if mouse over row
    @Override
    protected void paintRow(Graphics g, Rectangle clipBounds,
                            Insets insets, Rectangle bounds, TreePath path,
                            int row, boolean isExpanded,
                            boolean hasBeenExpanded, boolean isLeaf) {
        // Don't paint the renderer if editing this row.
        if(editingComponent != null && editingRow == row)
            return;

        int leadIndex;

        if(tree.hasFocus())
            leadIndex = getLeadSelectionRow();
        else
            leadIndex = -1;

        Component component = ((FileNameRenderer) t.getCellRenderer()).getTreeCellRendererComponent
                      (tree, path.getLastPathComponent(),
                       tree.isRowSelected(row), isExpanded, isLeaf, row,
                       (leadIndex == row), (row == uH.getRow()));

        rendererPane.paintComponent(g, component, tree, bounds.x, bounds.y,
                                    bounds.width, bounds.height, true);
    }

    //Small utility class used for retrieving information so that
    //tasks such as adding a rollover icon or rollover background
    //can be completed
    private class UpdateHandler extends BasicTreeUI.MouseHandler {
        private JTree t = null;
        private int xPos = 0;
        private int yPos = 0;

        public UpdateHandler(JTree tree) {
            t = tree;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            xPos = e.getX();
            yPos = e.getY();
            t.repaint();
        }

        public int getXPos() {
            return xPos;
        }

        public int getYPos() {
            return yPos;
        }

        public int getRow() {
            return t.getRowForLocation(xPos, yPos);
        }

        public int getRowHandle() {
            return getRowForPath(t, getClosestPathForLocation(t, xPos, yPos));
        }
    }

    //Method used for fade handles in or out
    public void fadeHandles(boolean show, int msDur) {
        Timer time = new Timer((int) Math.floor(msDur / 25), new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(show)
                    count++;
                else
                    count--;

                val = count * 0.04F;
                setCollapsedIcon(new AlphaImageIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/closed.png") , val));
                setExpandedIcon(new AlphaImageIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/open.png") , val));
                setRolloverIcon(new AlphaImageIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/rollover.png") , val));

                if(count == 0 || count == 25)
                    ((javax.swing.Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                t.repaint();
            }
        });

        timers.add(time);
        for(javax.swing.Timer timer : timers) {
            timer.stop();
        }

        time.start();
    }

    //Methods used for remove lines
    public void removeLines(boolean ShowLines) {
        lines = ShowLines;
    }

    public void removeLines(boolean ShowLines, boolean dashedLines) {
        lines = ShowLines;
        lineTypeDashed = dashedLines;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintDropLine(Graphics g) {
        if(!lines) {
            JTree.DropLocation loc = tree.getDropLocation();
            if (!isDropLine(loc))
                return;

            Color c = UIManager.getColor("Tree.dropLineColor");
            if (c != null) {
                g.setColor(c);
                Rectangle rect = getDropLineRect(loc);
                g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintHorizontalLine(Graphics g, JComponent c, int y, int left, int right) {
        if(!lines) {
            if (lineTypeDashed)
                drawDashedHorizontalLine(g, y, left, right);
            else
                g.drawLine(left, y, right, y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintVerticalLine(Graphics g, JComponent c, int x, int top, int bottom) {
        if(!lines) {
            if (lineTypeDashed)
                drawDashedVerticalLine(g, x, top, bottom);
            else
                g.drawLine(x, top, x, bottom);
        }
    }
}
```

Any other comments, tips or suggestions are welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Very clean code.

Comment: I am not going to downvote your question or something, but when I run it, I only get a window, but no action. I use Mac OS.

Comment: @coderodde I apologise. I wrote it on Windows. The problem will reside with `ComputerDirectoryTreeModel.java` - `private boolean addable(File path)` where the descriptions decide whether a drive is added. In Windows it is `Local Drive` and `USB Drive`. I don't know what it is in Mac

Comment: It's a lot of code to dig through, and I'm not sure if I can allocate enough time for a thorough review. But I wonder what the *performance* issue referred to. From a quick glance, I think that caching the `ImageIcon` instances that are used in `getTreeCellRendererComponent` might be beneficial, **but** `ImageIcon` should already do some caching internally, so this *might* not be necessary. A side note, *might* be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864538/how-to-fully-expand-a-large-jtree-efficiently

Comment: Try to return always `true` in `addable`. Does it work the same way?

Comment: @coderodde Whilst this does work I did not want it to work in this way as it also detects network drives which I did not want it to do for my purposes

Comment: @Marco13 Thank you for the comment. I should have further specified and have updated the question with the information

Comment: `ArrayList<Timer> timers = new ArrayList<Timer>();` I suggest you use `List` on the left hand side. What's important is that `timers` will have list functionality, not its implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I posted this question. But there are a few performance issues with the original code. The main ones being with methods such as `getChild`, `getChildCount`, `hasDirectory`, `listDirectories`.

The issue with `hasDirectory` and `listDirectories` was about how the files were listed and the method of verification used for checking if a directory had any sub directories. The big performance restriction was `file.listFiles()`; especially, with some of the bigger files. This was replaced with the methodology below.

```
//Written to improve performance of listDirectories(path) != 0
private boolean hasDirectory(File path) {
    //System.out.println("Testing: " + path.getAbsolutePath());
    Path dir = Paths.get(path.getAbsolutePath());
    DirectoryStream<Path> stream;
    try {
        stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir);
        for(Path p : stream) {
            //System.out.println("Testing for Children: " + p.toString());
            DirectoryStream<Path> tempStream;
            try {
                tempStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(p);
                tempStream.close();
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //System.out.println("Not a accessible dir");
            }
        }
        stream.close();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //System.out.println("Not a accessible dir");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The issue with `getChild` and `getChildCount` was they called very expensive functions such as `listDirectories` very often. To fix this I created a way of storing the results of `listDirectories`. In other words I used a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). This made searching for already existing results very quick. The method now looks a bit like this.

```
private File[] listDirectories(File path) {
    File[] files = DataStore.DATA_STORE.get(path.getAbsolutePath());

    if(files == null) {
        List<File> directories = new ArrayList<File>();
        for(File temp : path.listFiles()) {
            Path dir = Paths.get(temp.getAbsolutePath());
            DirectoryStream<Path> stream;
            try {
                stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir);
                stream.close();
                directories.add(temp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //System.out.println("Not a accessible dir");
            }
        }

        files = directories.toArray(new File[0]);
        DataStore.DATA_STORE.put(path.getAbsolutePath(), files);
        return files;
    }

    return files;
}
```

The full code can be found on this [Bitbucket Repository](https://bitbucket.org/Dan360/jdirectorytree/src/master/JDirectoryTree/src/tree/).

Answer (score 1):

Very clean code, I don't have much bad to say about it. As a cherry on top of the cake, you could center out the window:

```
private void moveToCenter() {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    Dimension screenDimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                                       .getScreenSize();
    setLocation((screenDimension.width - width) / 2, 
                (screenDimension.height - height) / 2);
}
```

Call it in the constructor of `JFileTreeIE`.

Also, if you plan to work on GUI software in Java, I suggest you migrate to JavaFX.

**Edit: Mac OS X**

I made it work on Mac by returning unconditionally `true` in `ComputerDirectoryTreeModel.addable()`.

**Advice 1**

If the `if` or `else` statement is a one-liner you omit the curly braces. I, however, suggest that you add them. That will add up to the maintainability of your code, since if the maintainer wants to add a statement or two to an, say, `if`-block, he/she don't have to type them themselves.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `window.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` should have the same effect as your `moveToCenter` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and advice. It helps knowing that the program is not cross platform. I will start to add code to support that

Comment: @Marco13 [Does not seem to work flawlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480102/java-jframe-setlocationrelativetonull-not-centering-the-window-on-ubuntu-10-0).

Comment: @coderodde The linked question might just have been caused by calling it *before* determining the size of the frame. It has to be called after the size has been set (via `setSize` or `pack`). (But of course, I can't test it on all OSes/Window managers right now...)

Comment: @Marco13 You are correct, sir. Seems to use some nonsensical width/height values.